# Getting data from REST API and storing it in Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

Does it make sense to get data from REST API and store it as JSON in an Azure Data Lake? Or the data should be stored directly into Azure SQL?

I've tried both options, but it's not clear in which scenario it is worth to save the data into Azure Data Lake.

Comment: Not sure there's any way to answer this objectively, without knowing specifics. This really is a general opinion-solicitation question, without any details. SQL DB and Data Lake are two very different services / storage options, and what you use will depend heavily on your app, and what you're doing with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is a perfectly normal pattern that has emerged for collecting large volumes in particular.  Writing to a database is great *but* there are (at least) two aspects to consider:

1. schema-on-write - you have to know the schema *before* you write to the database.  That means all columns, all datatypes, nullability, collation even before you can even think about writing a record.  How are you going to handle the schema of your JSON changing for example?
2. transaction logging - most Microsoft SQL databases work with write-ahead-log or WAL, which means the transaction logging has to complete before the transaction is considered complete as part of an ACID transaction.  What will happen in situations of heavy load on the database or high concurrency - queuing and blocking.  Often these things take milliseconds but low tiers etc come into play.  Alternate patterns like eventual consistency eg with Cosmos are a possibility if you need that sort of thing.

Data Lakes in contract are **schema-on-read**, ie you do not have to know the schema in order to write to the lake, so you can just land it and figure out the other stuff later.

This does not necessarily apply to your other question about Synapse as you run the risk of losing your perfectly good SQL Server datatypes.  Look at one of the [migration wizards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/migration-guides/migrate-to-synapse-analytics-guide?tabs=migratefromSQLServer) for that instead.

Comment: What's a "perfectly normal pattern?" The OP is asking for opinions on storing data in SQL DB or Data Lake. And there is no way to answer this objectively. Also, there are many other things to consider, aside from schema and transaction logging. But again: there is nothing in the original question to work with: no specific need; no issue(s); no code; no use cases; no queries; no transforms; just a question about which to write data to, from some (unknown) REST endpoint: SQL DB vs Data Lake.

Comment: @wBob, somebody turns on the light, thank you for the useful insights, now is clearer how to take my decision.

Comment: I need to get data from an API, I know the schema in advance (I just need few columns) and your answers clarifies. Cosmos DB is also a valid option to consider.