# Intermediate storage of the relational data into Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

Given a set of on-premises relational databases (SQL Server), is it worth to save the data into Azure Data Lake before processing into Azure Synapse?

If yes, what are the options to transfer the data? I've seen BCP/azcopy as an alternative, but are there other options?

Comment: There's really no way to answer this, as it's opinion-soliciting (as is your other question regarding using data lake, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68243347/272109). I would suggest reading up on data lake, and on hot-path/cold-path data processing. Then, post specific questions as you run into issues. Also: aside from a broad/opinion-based question on using Data Lake, you're also asking a generic question about transferring data (to Data Lake? Synapse?). Recommendation questions are off-topic. There is considerable documentation on both Data Lake and Synapse - I suggest starting there.

Answer (score 1):

> Given a set of on-premises relational databases (SQL Server), is it
> worth to save the data into Azure Data Lake before processing into
> Azure Synapse?

Its depends on the use case  , but since the data is at this time in premise , you have already invested in the server space with compute , but then if you are futuristic and think of how much compute and server space you will take , then moving to ADLS will make more snse . Also with the Synapse you will pay for the query which you run .

You mentioned BCP , I doubt if that will help here , you can use Azure data factory , azcopy  etc .